# select not null column collection query syntax in Magento2.2.0

Tags: magento2, query

This is my query, I want to execute in Magento2 function I have read some collection syntax of Magento2 but get confuse, can any one please write it in collection query syntax?

Thanks!!!

```
select * from catalog_product_flat_19 where image IS NOT NULL
```

I want to define this query in below function :

```
 protected function _getAllProductProductCollection()
    {
     $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
     $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

     $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
            ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PAGE_VAR_NAME, 1));

        $conditions = $this->getConditions();
        $conditions->collectValidatedAttributes($collection);
        $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($collection, $conditions);

        return $collection;
    }
```